# implementing JMP in flex

Tags: assembly, apache-flex

My task is to implement interpreter of assembly-like language using Flex.

There are such commands as:

> add x y z, (z = x + y)
>
> sub x y z, (z = x - y)
>
> mul x y z, (z = x * y)
>
> div x y z, (z = x / y)
>
> let x 10, (x = 10)
>
> mov x y, (y = x)

Implementing interpreter of this commands is pretty easy using Flex.

I have stuck with implementing `JMP line, (current line = line)` instruction. I have no idea how to reset Flex current parsing line or something like that.

Comment: You must create some small virtual machine that will fetch instructions from some array and execute/invoke appropriate routine. JMP will be just fetching instruction from given array index. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`JMP` instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_%28x86_instruction%29) simply modifies the [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pointer) with the address of the target instruction. So, this [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) you are making needs a PC register.

It really is that simple. Don't overthink this. Keep in mind, they created JMP instructions out of [vacuum tubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_tube) half a century ago. That puts a severe limit on complexity.